# Buildroot - cubieboard 2 not booting

Tags: linux, arm, busybox, buildroot

I just borrowed cubieboard2 from my friend and tried to boot it up.
I connected power to 2A USB charger, hdmi to my display and keyboard to USB.
Red (Power) light turned on.

**Whithout SD card** system boots from NAND, kernel messages shows up, but hangs on

```
[     17.000000] Mali display drivers loaded (SOMETHING LIKE THAT)
```

Nothing more is happening, but system is responding, because when I insert SD card it shows propper mesage:

```
[    800.000000] sd card info...
```

The default system on NAND should be android (my friend didnt touch it), but I'm not able to get anything more then kernel log

**With lubuntu SD card** system boots up properly, but the first image I get is desktop. After power on - screen turns on, but is whole black, no messages at all. After about 3 minutes desktop shows up.

**With default cubieboard2 busybox** created exactly as on http://www.smida.it/geekeries/cubieboard-buildroot.php - this is the most frustrating part! It took about 5 hours to make image using virtual gentoo machine on my pc. After that i created SD card with my OS. When I inserted SD card and booted device - screen turns on, there is some SD card activity, but no image at all. Screen is black (but turned on), SD activity LED blinks for a moment and then... nothing. Num-lock responds, pressing random keys - no SD card activity, but alt-ctr-del gives board a restart.

- How can I make my board working?
- Is there any way to 'debug' it? By connecting serial interface or something like that?
- Can I 'emulate' image on my gentoo virtual machine using qemu?
- Maybe there is obvious mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally got solution.

In fact my board was booting and everything was fine.
But in inittab the only tty was ttyS0 which was serial tty.

After adding getty with /dev/tty1 everything works fine.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. However, `ttyS0` worked for me.