# how to set up kernel virtual machine develop environment?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kvm

As i debug the kernel, the develop environment is qemu + busybox.But i cant used to study and develop kernel virtual machine.

It can set up break point, step by step the flow of codes.

Is there any similar method to debug kernel virtual machine ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Buildroot - cubieboard 2 not booting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23710893/3345375).